# Can I save everyone in one day?

Tags: the-sexy-brutale

Is it possible to save every guest in The Sexy Brutale in one day, assuming all of the masks have been unlocked.

> I know that the Marquis is saved in a special area of the mansion, so I don't think it's possible to save him at the same time as the other guests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it is not possible, because the game won't allow you to. If you save someone that you are not supposed to be saving right now, the game will stop and go back to the beginning of the day.

Comment: Is this true at the end of the game when you get the choice of restarting the day, or end the loop?